# How to set up an image in an div using backgroundImage?

Tags: reactjs, image

I have an div in which I have to display a photo using backgroundImage.
I have an object in which an as URL path for the image which I later on return from the obect.
I made the following code :

```
import React from 'react' 
import './user.css';


 const User = ({name,img,position,names}) => {
return ( <div className = 'card'>
    <div id='image' style={{ 
  backgroundImage: `url({${img}})` 
}}></div>
    <p className = 'card_name' id = 'based'>{name}</p>
    <p className = 'card_position'>{position}</p>
    <p>{names + ' '}</p>
</div>
 );
}

export default User;
```

When I try to run the page I dont have any errors but my image does not appear on the page. What my seem to be the problem?

Comment: Please, `console.log` the URL and check if that URL, if opened in another browser tab, shows up the image. Then check if the CSS is letting the image to have the right size...

Comment: It was my bad the image just didnt have the right size to show on the page. But is there any way to make the image size to fit the container, seems to work really easy on img tags, but doesnt work on my div tag.

Comment: Well, check the answer @Gideon Bamuleseyo provided, and, about CSS, https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_background-size.asp so like `background-size: cover;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra parentheses on the value you are passing to the URL, Try this:
You also need to add a height and width to the div

```
 style={{
            height: "200px", 
            width: "100%",
            backgroundImage: `url(${img})`,
          }}
```

Comment: Other valuable properties you may want to add depending on your desired look could be object-fit and background-repeat. Example
 `objectFit: "cover",`
 `backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",`